# How to view an anonymous exception in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, exception

Suppose I have some code that looks like this:

```
try
{
    CallMyFaultyFunction();
    return true;
}
catch
{     // <-- Breakpoint here
    return false;
}
```

I know it's bad to convert an exception to a `bool`, but sometimes you need to. Let's not discuss this.

During a debugging session, I would like to know the details of the exception, but because it the exception doesn't have a name, I can't view it. Is there some other way to watch it. I know I can replace the code with `catch (Exception exc)`, but I don't want to do that (requires restart).

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The sample is written in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what language this is. I'm guessing C#.

If you set a breakpoint inside a statement inside your `catch` block, then when an exception is caught you will see an entry in the Locals window called `$exception`, you can expand it like any other variable and also manipulate it in the Immediate window or the QuickWatch window by typing it by name.

The `$exception` value is an example of a Pseudovariable. They are documented in this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx

C# also has the `$user` psuedovariable.